# synthesis and Implement RTL design in verilog

Tags: verilog

I want to synthesis RTL design which sort data in memory. I am not sure that I need to synthesis the module with test bench or without it?

Comment: You need a synthesis tool... test benches are for simulation and testing before synthesis. They don't get synthesized.

Answer (score 1):

You need to synthesis the module without test bench.